# Trying to use the %name% function in Model Builder to keep the original files name, but its not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-000354

I am building a rather large model.  And I am trying to keep the files original name in the output file.  Example being.  Original File is called: Line.shp.  I want to dissolve Line.shp so in model builder I write the output dissolved files name as %Name%_dissolve.

However, I keep getting this error: ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters

Comment: Are you _actually_ creating shapefiles as suggested by your question or geodatabase featureclasses? "Line.shp" would be an invalid featureClass name as you have a dot in it.

Comment: Creating a shapefile.  Also the "Line" name is just an example, and the .shp is simply the extension.

Comment: OK so what is not an example what are you using?

Answer (score 4):

On the ModelBuilder menu tab, in the Insert group.

Select Tools (these are "Model Only Tools"), select "Parse Path".

After tool appears, click the link button on the toolbar.

Make a link between your Line shapefile and the Parse Path tool.

Double click to bring up tool properties.

From the Parse Type parameter, select File Name.

Click OK.

The output of the tool should be "Value".

For the output file name use "%Value%_dissolve".